# jump up on a new page in SPA

Tags: javascript, html, css, single-page-application

I'm making my portfolio as a single page app, however when I scroll down and click on to another page, it doesn't start from the top, like a normal website would, but on the middle of the page. So if I scroll down the front page and click on a link that redirects me to a new page, how far down I was on the last page thats how far down I am on the new page. How do I fix this?

I want, when I click on a link to a new page, to jump up and start at the start of the page.

I understand that it is in the same HTML document so the browser doesn't know that it is a new page, so I have to tell it, but how?

Javascript:

```
const app = {
    pages: [],
    show: new Event('show'),
    init: function(){
        app.pages = document.querySelectorAll('.page');
        app.pages.forEach((pg)=>{
            pg.addEventListener('show', app.pageShown);
        })

        document.querySelectorAll('.nav-link').forEach((link)=>{
            link.addEventListener('click', app.nav);
        })
        history.replaceState({}, 'Home', '#home');
        window.addEventListener('popstate', app.poppin);
    },
    nav: function(ev){
        ev.preventDefault();
        let currentPage = ev.target.getAttribute('data-target');
        document.querySelector('.active').classList.remove('active');
        document.getElementById(currentPage).classList.add('active');
        console.log(currentPage)
        history.pushState({}, currentPage, `#${currentPage}`);
        document.getElementById(currentPage).dispatchEvent(app.show);
    },
    pageShown: function(ev){
        console.log('Page', ev.target.id, 'just shown');
        let h1 = ev.target.querySelector('h1');
        h1.classList.add('big')
        setTimeout((h)=>{
            h.classList.remove('big');
        }, 1200, h1);
    },
    poppin: function(ev){
        console.log(location.hash, 'popstate event');
        let hash = location.hash.replace('#' ,'');
        document.querySelector('.active').classList.remove('active');
        document.getElementById(hash).classList.add('active');
        console.log(hash)
        //history.pushState({}, currentPage, `#${currentPage}`);
        document.getElementById(hash).dispatchEvent(app.show);
    }
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', app.init);
```

CSS:

```
.page {
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}

.active {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Hi there, could you please post your code? That way we can help identify if something within your code is causing the issue :)

Comment: with another app, do you mean an external page or just `mywebsite.com/somepage`

Comment: just in a html document

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution may be to add this

```
document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0; // for some older browsers
window.scrollTo(0,0) // newer browsers
```

to the `nav` function (assuming that's the one that switches your SPA "pages".)